# Regular expression in mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, regex, database, mysql-python

I have stored certain regular expressions in mysql database.When I access the same with cursor.fetchone() and use the regular expression in re.match() function,the result is not as intended whereas if I type the same regular expression as a parameter to the re.match() function,it is working...can anyone please tell me the solution..urgent plzzz..

Comment: urgent plzzz.. We are here to help, not to assist :-) The community is not payed support ;-)

Comment: If you need an urgent response, the least you can do is provide enough information to answer the question. *What* is the regular expression as a string, and as it appears in your database, and how are you using it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you compile the regular expression.

```
# Assuming 'pattern' is the string returned from the database query.

prog = re.compile(pattern)
result = prog.match(string)
```

or

```
result = re.match(pattern, string)
```

More information at http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Comment: Thank you Sir...Sorry for the wrong info if it makes a difference....I am using re.search() function..i tried what you told but still i am unable to get the intended result...this is my code    row=cursor.fetchone()     p=re.compile(row[1])   check2 = p.search(input)

Comment: Could you update your question with your code and expect inputs and outputs?

Comment: Make sure that `row[1]` exist before you use it. The problem might be with `row[1]`

Comment: You should accept an answers. Or tell everyone else how you solved the problem.